# Add Trino dataset to Apache Superset

Tags: kubernetes, apache-superset, trino

I have currently Trino deployed in my Kubernetes cluster using the official [Trino(trinodb) Helm Chart](https://github.com/trinodb/charts). In the same way I deployed [Apache superset](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/helm/superset/Chart.yaml).

- Using port forwarding of trino to 8080 and superset to 8088, I am able to access the UI for both from localhost but also I am able to use the trino command line API to query trino using:

  ./trino --server http:localhost:8080
- I don't have any authentication set
- mysql is setup correctly as Trino catalog

when I try to add Trino as dataset for Superset using either of the following sqlalchemy URLs:

```
trino://trino@localhost:8080/mysql
trino://localhost:8080/mysql
```

When I test the connection from Superset UI, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Could not load database driver: TrinoEngineSpec

Please advise how I could solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install `sqlalchemy-trino` to make the trino driver available.

Add these lines to your `values.yaml` file:

```yaml
additionalRequirements:
  - sqlalchemy-trino

bootstrapScript: |
  #!/bin/bash
  pip install sqlalchemy-trino &&\
  if [ ! -f ~/bootstrap ]; then echo "Running Superset with uid {{ .Values.runAsUser }}" > ~/bootstrap; fi
```

If you want more details about the problem, see this [Github issue](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/13640).

I added two options that do the same thing because in some versions the `additionalRequirements` doesn't work and you may need the `bootstrapScript` option to install the driver.